# NumberFormatException while filling ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to fill an array without knowing its size. I used ArrayList to do this

```
        String filename = "C:\\tmTest.123";
    int tmHex;
    FileInputStream in = null;
    ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();        

    try
    {            
        in = new FileInputStream(filename); 

        while((tmHex = in.read()) != -1)
        {                
            bytes.add(Byte.parseByte("", tmHex));

        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(NARSS02.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

But I got an exception NumberFormatException. Why ?
and if there is any other method to fill the array during reading bytes from the file.

Comment: `""` is not a valid numerical string.

Comment: You should use `List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();`, since `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List` - unrelated to the concrete question.

Answer (score 1):

[From the Java API:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (parseByte method summary)

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the
>   following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix    is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than    Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of    the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus    sign '-'
>     ('\u002D') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type byte.